# change network delay in ned file as a parameter

Tags: omnet++

is it possible to change the delay value of delay from being something static in the ned file (like it currently is) to some parameter set in the omnetpp.ini file?

this is my .ned file (mainly the tictoc8 from the omnet++ tutorial).

```
    simple Ping8
{
    parameters:
        @display("i=device/pc");
        
    gates:
        input in;
        output out;
}

simple Pong8
{
    parameters:
        @display("i=device/pc");
        //double d = default(0.5);
    gates:
        input in;
        output out;
}

network PingPong8
{
    
    @display("bgb=540,253");
    submodules:
        ping: Ping8 {
            parameters:
                @display("i=,cyan;p=32,145");
        }
        pong: Pong8 {
            parameters:
                @display("i=,gold;p=499,145");
        }
    connections:
        
        ping.out --> {  delay = 50ms; } --> pong.in;
        ping.in <-- {  delay = 50ms; } <-- pong.out;
}
```

I want to change the value in the PingPong8 connections delay value to something I set in the omnetpp.ini file.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Create a parameter at network level and use that parameter to set `delay` in the connections section. Top level networks behave exactly like any other compound module, except they don't have gates.